# Drupal. Two question from newbie

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

Could somebody give an answers for my question?

1. How to count clicks on outside URL to another webpage.
2. I have content type that can have one category (taxonomy). In node view I want to add block below with listing of links to nodes from current node category. How can I accomplish this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use javascript along with Google analytics. You need to add a click handler to the external links that stores the click.  This can be done pretty simple with regex and jquery.
2. You should be able to do this with the views module. It allow you to build list display of content pretty easily with an interface. It can be a bit tricky with taxonomy since it's a one to many relationship. It might be easier for you to build the block yourself in a custom module. It depends how well you know views, Drupal/PHP.